# Fallback function calls get reverted

Tags: solidity, transactions, fallback-function

I created a contract which mints tokens when the `msg.value` is higher or equal to the token(ticket) price. 
Unfortunately when I send a transaction to the contract fallback it gets reverted.
It's my fallback:

```
function() public payable {
    require(now < ticketExpiryDateTimestamp, "This sale has been completed");
    require(emitedTickets < maxTicketsSupply, "Sold out");
    uint _ticketsAmount = msg.value / ticketPrice;
    require(_ticketsAmount < maxTicketsSupply, "You can't buy more tickets than the emitted number");
    require(_ticketsAmount > 0, "You did not pay enough to buy any ticket");
    transfer(msg.sender, msg.value - _ticketsAmount * ticketPrice);
    mint(msg.sender, _ticketsAmount);
    emitedTickets += _ticketsAmount;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably easiest is to comment out the `require` statements one by one and see which one causes the revert. This way you'll find out which value is problematic.

Comment: Comment one line at a time, until you find which line is causing the problem. Since we don't have the rest of your contract, we cannot do it ourselves (and you should be the one to do it in any case).

Comment: My contract is not secret. https://pastebin.com/kYSCsB4s. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xcc67490c224ad4756bf349240744abff7ff9fe0d

Comment: Simply identify the require which revert. You can do that both inserting a label to be returned by the require as in: require (a>0, “error 1”); OR commenting them all out and reintroducing each of them one by one. After this please update the question

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to one of the require statements . try removing these require statements one by one and check which one is causing this

Comment: I checked it, the reason is gas estimation inside the fallback

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_mint` rather than `mint`.  Function `mint` is public and requires caller to be authorized minter, while `_mint` is internal, thus it may be called only from within the same smart contract, and it does not perform any authorization checks.

Answer (score 0):

This COULD be an arithmetic error based on the code you shared. Try ascertaining that the `msg.value` in the `transfer(msg.sender, msg.value - _ticketsAmount * ticketPrice);` is not less than `_ticketsAmounts * ticketPrice`